# Favorite Tags combination

Tags: support, tag-watching

Is it possible to add a combination of tags as a favorite?
for example adding the combination of `c#` and `android` will highlight question with these 2 tags attached to them.

Comment: No, there's only "OR" operator between the tags. Since "no" isn't really a valid answer, think it's more appropriate to close this as dupe of existing feature request asking for the same thing to be added.